# Node.js on public server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, webserver

I am learning to use node.js on a public server as a open line from server to clients (https://github.com/iamshaunjp/websockets-playlist/tree/lesson-5).
I have done a youtube tutorial to create a chat server / client. This works on my own machine.

The server code (index.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');

// App setup
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(4000, function () {
    console.log('listening to request on port 4000');
})

// Static files
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Socket setup
var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);

    socket.on('chat', function (data) {
        io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
    });

    socket.on('typing', function (data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data);
    });
});
```

The browser code (/public/chat.js):

```
// Make connection
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');

// Query DOM
var message = document.getElementById('message');
var handle = document.getElementById('handle');
var btn = document.getElementById('send');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

// Emit events

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    socket.emit('chat', {
        message: message.value,
        handle: handle.value
    });
});

message.addEventListener('keypress', function () {
    socket.emit('typing', handle.value);
});

// Listen for events

socket.on('chat', function (data) {
    feedback.innerHTML = '';
    output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.handle + ':</strong>' + data.message + '</p>';
});

socket.on('typing', function (data) {
    feedback.innerHTML = '<p><em>' + data + ' is typing a message...</em></p>';
});
```

The browser code (public/index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Websockets 101</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
    <link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <div id="mario-chat">
        <div id="chat-window">
            <div id="output"></div>
            <div id="feedback"></div>
        </div>
        <input id="handle" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
        <input id="message" type="text" placeholder="Message" />
        <button id="send">Send</button>
    </div>
    <script src="/chat.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i go to http://localhost:4000 i see the chat screen and i can chat (to multiple browser windows).

now i want to upload my code to the ubuntu development server but i can't get it working. I have installed Node.js on the server and when i type node -v i get the version number so the installation is correct.

What is my next step? If i upload the code to the development server (http://devserver01/websocket/) it won't display my code because i don't have an index.html.

On the localhost i have used this code (package.json):

```
 {
  "name": "websocket",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "websocket",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  },
}
```

If i go to http://devserver01/websocket/ it doesnt work (ofcourse), but also http://devserver01:4000 doesn't work (also ofcourse because it can't know it has to go to the js file).

But i cannot find any information on how to deploy this on a remote linux machine.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Did you put `index.html`and `chat.js` in the `public` directory on your ubuntu server and is that `public` directory in the right location where `index.js` can reference it as `public`?  What is the exact error you get in the browser when you try to point the browser at the root of your dev server?

Comment: I think i already got it working. I don't need to go to the port number, i need to put the files which are now in the public folder in an accessible folder. At the server i need to start the node server with "node /var/nodejs/index.js". That works. The only "problem" now is that the server opens port 4000 (which i didn't do myself) so everyone can send messages to my server. Am i able to keep the port close from the outside?